# Linux script: how to split a text into different files with match pattern

Tags: linux, shell, split, pattern-matching

For example:
I have a text as following:

```
Jul 11 xxxx  xxxx start xxxxx
....
....
....
Jul 11 xxxx  xxxx stop xxxxx
Jul 11 xxxx  xxxx start xxxxx
....
....
....
Jul 11 xxxx  xxxx stop xxxxx
....
```

now I want to split the above text file into different files based on "start" and "stop", like

```
/***text1.txt******/
Jul 11 xxxx  xxxx start xxxxx
....
....
....
Jul 11 xxxx  xxxx stop xxxxx

/***text2.txt******/
Jul 11 xxxx  xxxx start xxxxx
....
....
....
Jul 11 xxxx  xxxx stop xxxxx
```

How can I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can make it:

```
$ awk '{if ($0 ~ /start/) a++} {print >> "file"a}' file
```

#### Explanation

- `{if ($0 ~ /start/) a++}` looks for lines containing the word `start`. If so, increments the variable `a`, which is `0` by default.
- `{print >> "file"}'` prints `$0` (that is, the whole line) to a file called "file" in the same directory.
- `{print >> "file"a}` prints the line to a file called "file" + variable `a`, which happens to be 0, 1, 2... So it prints to `file1`, `file2`...

#### Test

```
$ cat a
Jul 11 xxxx  xxxx start xxxxx
....
....
....
Jul 11 xxxx  xxxx stop xxxxx
Jul 11 xxxx  xxxx start xxxxx
here begins 2nd file
....
....
....
Jul 11 xxxx  xxxx stop xxxxx
$ awk '{if ($0 ~ /start/) {a++}} {print >> "file"a}' a
$ cat file1
Jul 11 xxxx  xxxx start xxxxx
....
....
....
Jul 11 xxxx  xxxx stop xxxxx
$ cat file2
Jul 11 xxxx  xxxx start xxxxx
here begins 2nd file
....
....
....
Jul 11 xxxx  xxxx stop xxxxx
```

Answer (score 0):

With awk, 'if ($0 ~ )' is implicit.

```
awk 'BEGIN{a=0;b=0}  /start/{a++;b=1}    (b==1){print >> "file"a}   /stop/{b=0}' input_file.txt
```